# Remove CR from text file if subsequent line is shorter than X characters

Tags: regex, csv, text-files, ultraedit

I have a massive text/csv file with is 6 GB big.
When it was created an error happened and some new line characters (CRLF) have not been removed from fields so certain lines are broken

Here a simplified version:

e.g

```
Field1<TAB>Field2<TAB>Field3<TAB>Field4
Field1<TAB>Field2<TAB>Field3<TAB>Field4
Field1<TAB>Field2<TAB>Field3
<TAB>Field4
Field1<TAB>Field2<TAB>Field3<TAB>Field4
```

So field 3 in line 3 has a CR and therefore the line is broken

I don't want to recreate that CSV file which would take too long but there must be a way to fix this maybe with the help of regular expressions and a tool.

It's easy to identify broken lines. They are less than 50 characters long.
All good lines are longer than 50 characters

So I need a step which:
* identifies short lines
* removes the CRLF in front of that line
* does this for the whole file

I can create a macro in UltraEdit and search for Perl Regex

```
^.{0,50}$
```

and replace the CRLF in front. That works but takes way too long. Macros in UltraEdit are handy but very slow.

Is there an other way? Can I use a regex with some tool to search/replace?

Thanks,
Wolfgang

Comment: This can be done very efficient with UltraEdit as described at UE forum topic [Find lines in CSV file with less or more than X tabs within a line](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12524) by running manually or with a macro or script a __Replace in Files__ on this specific huge CSV file without opening it in UltraEdit at all. The replace is done without line counting, undo recording, window updates, etc. by not opening the file in UltraEdit, i.e. just opening the file in background and searching for bytes replaced by other bytes with processing file content in small chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for:

```
^(.{1,50})\n(.{1,50}\n)
```

and replace with:

```
$1$2
```

Demo (for broken lines at 30 characters or less instead): https://regex101.com/r/pr5JhW/1

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know a tool that can handle that for big files?

Comment: You're welcome. I personally would use awk, perl or Python for that.